# After the second click Modal is not showing in my react boostrap table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-modal, react-bootstrap-table, react-google-charts

Im usign react boostrap tables but after i click it once, the second time i click in my table the modal is not showing.

Here is my table component

```
const CustomTable = ({ setStateName, setShouldShow }) => {

  const handleTdClick = ( {name} ) => {
    setStateName(name);
    setShouldShow(true);
    
  };

  return (
    <Table striped bordered hover variant="dark" size="sm">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Estado</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          { estados.map(e => (
              <td key={e.id} onClick={ () => handleTdClick(e)}>
              {e.name}
              </td>
          ))}
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </Table>
  );
};
```

Here is the father component where the modal and the table is called as well as the '''shouldShow``` etc.

```
const MexiMap = () => {

  const [stateName, setStateName] = useState('');
  const [shouldShow, setShouldShow] = useState(false);

  const chartEvents = [{
    eventName: "ready",
    callback: ({ chartWrapper, google }) => {
      const chart = chartWrapper.getChart();
      google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, "select", e => {
        const id = chart.getSelection()[0].row;
        const name = getNombreEstadoById(id);
        setStateName(name);
        setShouldShow(true);
        setShouldShow(false);
        
      });
    }
  }]

  const options = {
    region: 'MX',
    resolution: 'provinces',
    colorAxis: { colors: ['#00853f', 'black', '#e31b23'] },
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
    datalessRegionColor: '#eeeeee',
    defaultColor: 'white',
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Chart
        width={'1500px'}
        height={'900px'}
        chartType="GeoChart"
        data={data}
        options={options}
        chartEvents={chartEvents}
      />

      <CustomModal name={stateName} showModal={shouldShow} />
      

      <CustomTable setStateName={setStateName} setShouldShow={setShouldShow} />
    </>
  );
};

export default MexiMap;
```

And here is the modal component:

```
const CustomModal = ({ name, showModal }) => {

  const [show, setShow] = useState(showModal);

  const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
  const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    showModal && setShow(true);
  }, [showModal]);

  return (
    <>
      <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title>{name}</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>Woohoo, you're reading this text in a modal!</Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleClose}>
            Close
          </Button>
          <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleClose}>
            Save Changes
          </Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
}

export default CustomModal;
```

Can anyone help me, how to fix the table so the modal shows everytime the table is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the modal state in the parent and in the child become out of sync.

Specifically here in the child, the `CustomModal`, component:

```
const CustomModal = ({ name, showModal }) => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(showModal);

  const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
  const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(showModal);
    showModal && setShow(true);
  }, [showModal]);

  // ...
};
```

When the `shouldShow` state in the `MexiMap` (parent) component is updated, this is correctly reflected in the modal behavior, since the first click opens the modal. On closing the modal `handleClose` is called, which sets `show` to `false`.

The problem with this is that this state is local to `CustomModal`. The parent component isn't aware that the modal state has changed, because `show` has changed and not `shouldShow`. `show` and `shouldShow` represent the same information, so these states should not hold different values.

What you can do instead is pass your parent components' `setShouldShow` to the CustomModal (child) component and use this function to update the `showModal` state.

Here's a simplified example of the approach:

```
const CustomModal = ({ name, showModal, setShowModal }) => {
  const handleClose = () => setShowModal(false);
  const handleShow = () => setShowModal(true);

  return (
    <>
      <Modal show={showModal} onHide={handleClose}>
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title>{name}</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>Woohoo, you're reading this text in a modal!</Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleClose}>
            Close
          </Button>
          <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleClose}>
            Save Changes
          </Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const [shouldShow, setShouldShow] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={() => setShouldShow(!shouldShow)}>Click</button>
      <CustomModal showModal={shouldShow} setShowModal={setShouldShow} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

This way we have a single source of truth, the `shouldShow` state tells us whether the modal should be shown or not.

Here's a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/prod-water-gh8e4?file=/src/App.js:862-883) that includes the implementation above and a simplified version of your original code that reproduces the problem.